# HTML two columns with one common scroll

Tags: html, css, css-multicolumn-layout

I need to have the page separated in two columns but I want them to share the same scroll. I need that if one of the columns gets too big and I scroll down, the smaller one goes down too even if that side shows nothing. I can only find people asking how to get two separated scrolls but that's what I have right now.

```css
.split {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Header!</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="split left">
    <p>Left Side</p>
  </div>
  <div class="split right">
    <p>Right Side</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

When I change the `position`, the two columns disappear.

Comment: please add your html code..

Comment: Do you need the code inside "split left" and "split right"? It's a lot with Drop-Down Lists, tables and photos.

Comment: give the fix `height` to `.split` class.. such as a `200px;`

Comment: now the scrolls are still separated and the columns dont go till the end of the page

Comment: it's not clear to me what you need.. will you share a screenshot or pic of expected result ?

Comment: FluffyKitten's answer is what I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add your "split" page into a container and let the container have the scroll bar.

The container can take the CSS you were using to create the scrollbar on your split divs, e.g.

```
.scrollcontainer {
  width:100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* update: instead of height: 100%, you can use this to allow for the header at the top*/
  bottom:0px;
  top:60px;
}
```

Now your split div just need to have the following:

```
.split {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

FYI - note the use of `position:absolute` here - this is to let you position the split divs using `left` and `right`.
`
**Working Snippet**

```css
.scrollcontainer {
  width:100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: auto;
  bottom:0px;
  top:60px;
}

.split {
  height:100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1>Header!</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="scrollcontainer">
  <div class="split left">
    <p>Left Side</p>
    <p>Left Side</p>
    <p>Left Side</p>
    <p>Left Side</p>
    <p>Left Side</p>
    <p>Left Side</p>
    <p>Left Side</p>
    <p>Left Side</p>
    <p>Left Side</p>
    <p>Left Side</p>
    <p>Left Side</p>
    <p>Left Side</p>
    <p>Left Side</p>
  </div>
  <div class="split right">
    <p>Right Side</p>
    <p>Right Side</p>
    <p>Right Side</p>
    <p>Right Side</p>
    <p>Right Side</p>
    <p>Right Side</p>
    <p>Right Side</p>
    <p>Right Side</p>
    <p>Right Side</p>
    <p>Right Side</p>
    <p>Right Side</p>
    <p>Right Side</p>
    <p>Right Side</p>
    <p>Right Side</p>
    <p>Right Side</p>
    <p>Right Side</p>
    <p>Right Side</p>
    <p>Right Side...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```